# SSRS: Trouble understanding Grouping in Report

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a relatively simple report that is 'working'.
It has a main Group based on an Expression - with one sort in the Group - and then another 'Group' named 'Details' under that in the Row Groups pane.

The Main Group is repeating itself for no reason that I can figure.
I expect that if there is a Group called 'A' - then all the Detail rows in that Group will display till the next Group - right?

Like this:

```
A
Bob      1   Texas
Jane     2   California
Devin    4   New York

B
Jack     3   Texas
Mary     6   Maine
Peter    5   Michigan

C
. . .
```

Instead, the report is doing something like this:

```
A
Bob      1   Texas
Jane     2   California

A
Devin    4   New York

B
Jack     3   Texas

B
Mary     6   Maine
Peter    5   Michigan

C
. . .
```

If I delete the Details Group I lose some data & the report goes from 5 pages [57 detail recs] to about two pages.
If I delete the Main Group as well - I go down to just one record in the entire report.

I need to keep all the data that is on the report - but have it Group correctly by the Main Group [without repeats of the Group Header] and then within each group - sort by a couple of different fields.

Any idea how I should go about Troubleshooting the issue?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be something that is **Grouping** your detail. Make sure that there isn't any grouping on it.

If you can't figure it out, try creating a new one using your old one as a template. I've wasted hours trying to figure out what an issue is but creating a new matrix just takes a few minutes.

I had copied all the cells from the old matrix to a new one I had created and it worked as the first one should have.

I've had this happen a few times and have since given up on trying to figure out why something doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The 'IIF . . . ' Expression for the Group By and the Expression in the Group Header had different field names in the 'False' argument of the two expressions. So the report was GROUPING by one field - but DISPLAYING another field as the Group Header.
I have never done something like that and I can't imagine why I ever WOULD . . . and perhaps that is why I only stumbled on the anomaly because I was copying the two expressions into Notepad to recreate the Matrix and then noticed the difference.
The two field names in the 'False' arguments of the IIF expressions are quite similar - and that was an added reason that it was almost 'camouflaged'.
This is resolved.

Thanks @Hannover Fist! Appreciate that. To copy all the cells, can you just 'lasso' them with the mouse and then Ctrl + C . . . & then create a new Matrix and Ctrl + V? I was on the verge of just re-creating the Matrix.